# Setting SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS can irreversibly break your site?

Tags: python, django

I'm wanting to implement `SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS` to my Django settings for extra security - however the warning from the Django docs is making me abit scared so I want some clarification. Here is what is says:

**SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS**

> Default: 0
>
> If set to a non-zero integer value, the SecurityMiddleware sets the HTTP Strict Transport Security header on all responses that do not
>   already have it.
>
> Warning:
>   Setting this incorrectly can irreversibly (for some time) break your site. Read the HTTP Strict Transport Security documentation first.

What has to happen for it to "break my site"? I read the `HTTP Strict Transport Security documentation` first and it didn't make it any clearer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

> HTTP Strict Transport Security lets a web site inform the browser that
>   it should never load the site using HTTP and should automatically
>   convert all attempts to access the site using HTTP to HTTPS requests
>   instead. It consists in one HTTP header, Strict-Transport-Security,
>   sent back by the server with the resource.

In other words, if you set the value of `SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS` to e.g. 518400 (6 days) your web server will inform your client's browser the first time he visits your site to exclusively access your website over `https` in the future. This applies to the entire defined period. If for any reason you no longer provide access to your website over `https` the browser couldn't access your services anymore.

Therefore, you should initially set this variable to a low value of like 60s and make sure that everything works as expected, otherwise you could prevent yourself and your client from visiting your site.

> Browsers properly respecting the `HSTS` header will refuse to allow
>   users to bypass warnings and connect to a site with an expired,
>   self-signed, or otherwise invalid SSL certificate. If you use HSTS,
>   make sure your certificates are in good shape and stay that way!
>   [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#http-strict-transport-security)

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by, `If for any reason you no longer provide access to your website over https the browser couldn't access your services anymore.`  Then just change the value of SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS and restart the server?

Comment: Yes, that's a bit misleading, I agree. You can override the HSTS expire time by resending the header field with a different value. But still, as long as you don't do that you may have trouble reaching your site.

Comment: @NoName if the ssl certificate expires, then that qualifies for `a reason you are unable to provide access over https`

Comment: If we remove this setting altogether from the settings.py file, will it still be irreverisble?